# how to get "new" and "delete" fully covered and not partially covered with gtest framework. vs 2015

Tags: c++, code-coverage, googletest

I'm using google test framework for unit testing my code and i encountered in a very strange issue.

I noticed that any line that contains dynamic allocation(new and delete), does not get full coverage even if the code runs through this lines.

I've made a simple example to demonstrate the problem:
lets say i have the following class:

```
class DummyClass // fully covered
{
public:
    int x;
    DummyClass() { x = 5; }; // fully covered
    ~DummyClass() { }; // fully covered
};
```

Now i have the following function that allocate this class statically and dynamically:

```
static void CoverageFunctionTest()
{
    // any logic here
    DummyClass staticVar1; // fully covered
    DummyClass* dynamicVar = new DummyClass();  // partially covered
    // any logic here
    DummyClass staticVar2; // fully covered
    delete dynamicVar;  // partially covered
}
```

The line with the "new" keyword and the line with the "delete"
 keyword are considered as partially covered and not fully covered.

The coverage for this function is: 88.24% even though we covered every single line in it, and the coverage for the class is 100%.

How can i get 100% code coverage for this function?

Ty!